# Why are items in the array being skipped?

Tags: powershell

I have a table

[image: table]

I have the following script

```
$Result = Query "SELECT [databasename], [servertypeA], [servertypeB] from table GROUP BY [databasename], [servertypeA], [servertypeB]"

$Servers = @()
$DB = @()

foreach($row in $Result)
{   
    $i++
    $DB += $row.Item("databasename")
    $Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA")
    $Servers += $row.Item("servertypeB")

    cmd /c "PS.bat $somescript.ps1 $($Servers[-1]) $($DB[-1])"
}
```

this results in:

```
db1 serverx
db1 servery
db2 serverx
db2 servery
```

it should be

```
db1 server1
db1 serverx
db1 servery
db2 server2
db2 serverx
db2 servery
```

why is `servertypeA` being skipped, i.e. `server1 and server2` in `$Server`?

I also tried this

```
$Result = Query "SELECT distinct [databasename], [servertypeA], [servertypeB] from table"
```

and its generating the same result

Comment: The query you wrote only returns four rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big change is to the query, to get the results you want, but note this also let me greatly simplify the loop:

```
$Result = Query "SELECT DISTINCT [databasename], [serverTypeA] As Server from table  UNION SELECT DISTINCT [databasename], [serverTypeB] from table"

foreach($row in $Result)
{   
    $DB = $row.Item("databasename")
    $Server = $row.Item("Server")

    cmd /c "PS.bat $somescript.ps1 $Server $DB"
}
```

Comment: so then i dont need $Servers = @()
$DB = @()?

Comment: You only need them if you want to use them later on. You don't need them to call this script. And even if you do want to use them later, I would say it's better to only keep _one_ collection, where the DB and the Server properties of the object in the collection, to better preserve the relationship between db and server.

Comment: so i just changed the code to how you have it, and this resulted in: db1 server1 first iteration, second iteration: db1db1 server1serverx, 3rd iteration db1db1db1 server1serverxservery. its now apending to the previous iterations

Comment: Make sure `$Server` doesn't still show a `+=` and isn't previously declared as an array.

Comment: THAT was it! THANK YOU :D. also i dont need the arrays nor do i need the -1 complex code. your script is much more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

Simples! In your loop you are doing 2 additions to the `$Servers` array, but only one call to your external script, in which you pass in only the last item in the `$Servers` array.

If you can forgive me straying beyond the strict question you have asked, how come you have elected to call Powershell, from cmd.exe, from Powershell? This would be a more usual approach:

```
foreach($row in $Result)
{   
    $i++
    $DB = $row.Item("databasename")
    $Servers = $row.Item("servertypeA"), $row.Item("servertypeB")

    & "$somescript.ps1" @($Servers) $DB
}
```

The value of eliminating the round-trip through cmd.exe is in:

- saving wasted processes
- ability to debug
- ability to capture all streams
- helpful error messages

I'm assuming that you define `$somescript` elsewhere. The exact syntax of the `&` call will depend on whether you've nicely defined your param block - it's always good to have something like this:

```
param
(
    [string[]]$Servers
    [string]$DB
)
```

**EDIT**

Since you've clarified what you need to pass in to `$somescript`, try this:

```
foreach($row in $Result)
{   
    $DB = $row.Item("databasename")
    & "$somescript.ps1" $row.Item("servertypeA") $DB
    & "$somescript.ps1" $row.Item("servertypeB") $DB
}
```

Comment: In the other script i have defined it this way: param(
    [string] $Server,
    [string] $DB
  ). unfortunately, i cant make $Server an array in this other script because its being passed directly as a connection string parameter.

Comment: also i tried this and it results in server1 serverx, server1 servery, server 2 serverx, server2 servery, basically skipping the $DB entirely

Comment: Yeah, that'll be because it's positionally binding to the param block in your other script, and only the first two items are going into the params. If you were to look, you'd find $DB in the $args automatic variable in the script. But anyway, I've added an edit to my answer that calls yr script twice per loop. HTH

Answer (score 1):

replace this below code

```
$DB += $row.Item("databasename")
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA")
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeB")
```

with

```
$DB += $row.Item("databasename")
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeA")
$DB += $row.Item("databasename")
$Servers += $row.Item("servertypeB")
```

Comment: just tried this. it still results in same output im getting, skipping server1 and server2